# Problema con Tailwind CSS "justify-between"

Tags: html, css, tailwind, flex

Estoy usando Tailwind, en mi menu quiero que se vea algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="navigation flex justify-between  items-center container">
  <vex-navigation-item></vex-navigation-item>
</div>
```

Sin embargo cuando coloco otra clase como "justify-center" o "justify-end" si me funciona.

justify-center:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Justify-end
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando coloco "justify-between" me coloca me esta colocando los items al principio dejando todo ese espacio sobrante para el final
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta darle este estilo a tu div `style="width: 100% !important"`

Comment: Hola Juan, sería conveniente que agregarás un mínimo de código para poder reproducir tu problema, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo esta sucediendo es que tu componente `vex-navigation-item` esta conteniendo el menu que te muestra por esta razón al darle `justify-center`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-blue-500 flex justify-between align-center">
  <div class="p-10 bg-blue-200">A</div>
  <div class="p-10 bg-blue-200">B</div>
  <div class="p-10 bg-blue-200">C</div>
</div>
```

ahora bien lo que hay que entender es que esta funcionando correctamente todo, sin embargo tu menú no esta funcionando de acuerdo a lo que buscas.

Tomando en cuenta el ejemplo anterior en la opción `B` vamos a agreegar todo tu menú:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-blue-500 flex justify-between">
  <div class="p-1 bg-blue-200">Item x</div>
  <div class="p-10 bg-red-200 flex justify-center">
    <div class="text-green-500">Item 1</div>
    <div class="">Item 2</div>
    <div class="text-green-500">Item 3</div>
    <div class="">Item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-blue-200">Item z</div>
</div>
```

en tu caso es como si `item x` no existiera. debes verificar como esta generando el html para que agreges las correspondientes clases.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <div class="bg-blue-500 flex justify-between">
      <div class="p-10 bg-red-200 flex justify-center">
        <div class="text-green-500">Item 1</div>
        <div class="">Item 2</div>
        <div class="text-green-500">Item 3</div>
        <div class="">Item 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-1 bg-blue-200">Item z</div>
    </div>
```

Por esta razon tu menú es empujado a la izquierda.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.